# Refine my regex for years and months in R

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to extract the years /months of experience in R language using the following regex, but

1. I am unable to refine it and make it short,
2. It is also extracting entries in which no numeric values are present, but only months/years are present.

I only need to extract the numeric values which are followed by years or months from particular documents in which they're found from the corpus, and store them in a list containing the document ID corresponding to which they're found

```
gregexpr("[0-9]{1,2}\\.?[0-9]{0,2}(\\+)?\\s*([Yy][Ee][Aa][Rr][Ss]|[Yy][Rr][Ss]|[Yy][Ee][Aa][Rr]|[Yy][Rr]?\\.?))"

gregexpr("[0-9]{0,2}(\\+)?\\s*([Mm][Oo][Nn][Tt][Hh][Ss]|[Mm][Oo][Nn][Tt][Hh]?\\.?)"
```

But it seems that I am making the regex too long. The case insensitive "\i" doesn't seem to work either. 
For reference there could be following combinations present in the corpus:-

```
3.5/ 3.5+ / 3+ / 16.5 / 15+ /16.5+  years/yrs./yrs of experience
6 / 6.5 / 16 / 16.5 months of experience
```

After extracting these strings I am planning to extract the numeric values and store them in lists of years and months seperately, followed by doc names.

Following is the code:

```
listYears <- c()
listMonths <- c()

print("Year containing Resumes are")
for (i in 1:l)
{
  k = regmatches(as.String(docs[[i]]), gregexpr("[0-9]{1,2}\\.?[0-9]{0,2}(\\+)?\\s*([Yy][Ee][Aa][Rr][Ss]|[Yy][Rr][Ss]|[Yy][Ee][Aa][Rr]|[Yy][Rr]?\\.?)", as.String(docs[[i]])))
  if (as.character(k) != "character(0)")
  {
    print(meta(docs[[i]])$id)
    print(k)
    len_k1 = list(meta(docs[[i]])$id)
    listYears = c(listYears,len_k1)
  }
  else
  {
    k = regmatches(as.String(docs[[i]]), gregexpr("[0-9]{0,2}(\\+)?\\s*([Mm][Oo][Nn][Tt][Hh][Ss]|[Mm][Oo][Nn][Tt][Hh]?\\.?)", as.String(docs[[i]])))
    if (as.character(k) != "character(0)")
    {
      print(meta(docs[[i]])$id)
      print(k)
      len_k2 = list(meta(docs[[i]])$id)
      listMonths = c(listMonths,len_k2)
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what your data looks like? Are they uniformly formatted, uniformly formatted but in more than one way or you need some form of fuzzy matching?

Comment: Hi. My data is in the form of a corpus made out of .doc files containing several Resumes. Each doc might contain strings like the following


1. .."Technical Architect having overall 17+ years of experience in IT industry developing, managing and delivering applications involving data architecting"

2. ...Lead Experience : Total 3.5 years of experience of leading a team.


3. ...Cross application environment with over 20 years of experience in information systems including 10 years supporting SAP.